# How do I gain access to my Microtik router after I mistakenly disabled the IP address?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-networking, mikrotik-routeros

I mistakenly disabled my mikrotik router IP and suddenly discovered that I lost internet connection and can no longer login to my router,neither the web interface nor winbox is able to connect me back to my router.
Please I need help to solve this issue

Comment: Find the documentation, do a factory reset, and set it up from scratch?

Comment: Mikrotik makes many different models of routers https://mikrotik.com/support . Please include all the information in your question we need, such as its model number, from the sticker which also has its serial number. Please click [edit] to add it to the question. Please do not click Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Answer (score 3):

If you have shell access to another Mikrotik router in the same subnet:

1. Use `/tool romon discover` to see if the router has RoMON enabled.
2. Use `/tool romon ssh <address>` to connect to your router by its RoMON ID.

If you have Winbox access to another Mikrotik router in the same subnet:

1. Enter the other router's details in Winbox, then click "Connect to RoMON" and see if your missing router shows up in the peer list. If it does, select it from the list and connect.

If the router has MAC-Telnet or MAC-Winbox enabled:

1. Find the MAC address written on the router.
2. Enter it directly into the Winbox address field, or use the `mac-telnet` tool on Linux.

(Note: On devices which have a range of MAC addresses – one per interface – you might need to try all of them until you find one that works.)

If the router has IPv6 enabled: connect to its link-local address.

1. Find the MAC address written on the router.
2. Invert bit 2 of the second digit from left, changing `0`↔`2`, or `4`↔`6`, or `8`↔`A`, or `C`↔`E`.
3. Insert FF:FE in the middle: `00:11:22:33:44:55` → `00:11:22:FF:FE:33:44:55`
4. Re-group to 4 digits and add prefix: `00:11:22:FF:FE:33:44:55` → `fe80::0011:22ff:fe33:4455`
5. On Windows, try directly entering this address into the Winbox address field in `[`brackets`]`.

   ```
   Address:    [fe80::0011:22ff:fe33:4455]
   ```
6. On Linux, append `%` and the interface name, then use the resulting address for SSH or telnet:

   ```
   ssh admin@fe80::0011:22ff:fe33:4455%wlan0
   telnet fe80::0011:22ff:fe33:4455%wlan0
   ```

(If you can't seem to find the correct address, then `ping ff02::2%wlan0` should provide hints.)

If the router has a serial console port:

1. Connect the serial console port to your PC (buy a USB-serial adapter if you need one).
2. Open a "serial terminal" app (e.g. HyperTerminal on Windows, picocom on Linux) and connect to the serial port. (RouterOS will by default try to detect the baud rate automatically.)
3. Press Enter a few times and you should get a login prompt.

If the router has a USB port (either type-A or type-microB):

1. Get a USB-serial adapter that is based on the Prolific pl2302 chip. (Others might also work, but pl2302 is known to work and is very common.)
2. Connect it to the router (using a USB OTG cable if needed).
3. Continue with the "serial port" instructions above.